# wkhtmltopdf jQuery.Deferred exception: 'null' is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, doxygen, wkhtmltopdf

I used Doxygen to create documentation in HTML and now I am trying to convert the HTML files to PDF using wkhtmltopdf but encountered the below error.
The PDF is generated but content is all blank.
I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt), Doxygen 1.9.4

The jQuery file should be the standard javascript that is generated from Doxygen step.

```
wkhtmltopdf --debug-javascript --enable-local-file-access *.html output.pdf
```

Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: file:///C:/Users/Downloads/Mik/html/jquery.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: 'null' is not an object
Warning: undefined:0 TypeError: 'null' is not an object
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done

```js
S.extend({
    Deferred: function(e) {
      var o = [
          ["notify", "progress", S.Callbacks("memory"), S.Callbacks("memory"), 2],
          ["resolve", "done", S.Callbacks("once memory"), S.Callbacks("once memory"), 0, "resolved"],
          ["reject", "fail", S.Callbacks("once memory"), S.Callbacks("once memory"), 1, "rejected"]
        ],
        i = "pending",
        a = {
          state: function() {
            return i
          },
          always: function() {
            return s.done(arguments).fail(arguments), this
          },
          "catch": function(e) {
            return a.then(null, e)
          },
          pipe: function() {
            var i = arguments;
            return S.Deferred(function(r) {
              S.each(o, function(e, t) {
                var n = m(i[t[4]]) && i[t[4]];
                s[t[1]](function() {
                  var e = n && n.apply(this, arguments);
                  e && m(e.promise) ? e.promise().progress(r.notify).done(r.resolve).fail(r.reject) : r[t[0] + "With"](this, n ? [e] : arguments)
                })
              }), i = null
            }).promise()
          },
          then: function(t, n, r) {
            var u = 0;

            function l(i, o, a, s) {
              return function() {
                var n = this,
                  r = arguments,
                  e = function() {
                    var e, t;
                    if (!(i < u)) {
                      if ((e = a.apply(n, r)) === o.promise()) throw new TypeError("Thenable self-resolution");
                      t = e && ("object" == typeof e || "function" == typeof e) && e.then, m(t) ? s ? t.call(e, l(u, o, R, s), l(u, o, M, s)) : (u++, t.call(e, l(u, o, R, s), l(u, o, M, s), l(u, o, R, o.notifyWith))) : (a !== R && (n = void 0, r = [e]), (s || o.resolveWith)(n, r))
                    }
                  },
                  t = s ? e : function() {
                    try {
                      e()
                    } catch (e) {
                      S.Deferred.exceptionHook && S.Deferred.exceptionHook(e, t.stackTrace), u <= i + 1 && (a !== M && (n = void 0, r = [e]), o.rejectWith(n, r))
                    }
                  };
                i ? t() : (S.Deferred.getStackHook && (t.stackTrace = S.Deferred.getStackHook()), C.setTimeout(t))
              }
            }
            return S.Deferred(function(e) {
              o[0][3].add(l(0, e, m(r) ? r : R, e.notifyWith)), o[1][3].add(l(0, e, m(t) ? t : R)), o[2][3].add(l(0, e, m(n) ? n : M))
            }).promise()
          },
          promise: function(e) {
            return null != e ? S.extend(e, a) : a
          }
        },
        s = {};
      return S.each(o, function(e, t) {
        var n = t[2],
          r = t[5];
        a[t[1]] = n.add, r && n.add(function() {
          i = r
        }, o[3 - e][2].disable, o[3 - e][3].disable, o[0][2].lock, o[0][3].lock), n.add(t[3].fire), s[t[0]] = function() {
          return s[t[0] + "With"](this === s ? void 0 : this, arguments), this
        }, s[t[0] + "With"] = n.fireWith
      }), a.promise(s), e && e.call(s, s), s
    },
    when: function(e) {
      var n = arguments.length,
        t = n,
        r = Array(t),
        i = s.call(arguments),
        o = S.Deferred(),
        a = function(t) {
          return function(e) {
            r[t] = this, i[t] = 1 < arguments.length ? s.call(arguments) : e, --n || o.resolveWith(r, i)
          }
        };
      if (n <= 1 && (I(e, o.done(a(t)).resolve, o.reject, !n), "pending" === o.state() || m(i[t] && i[t].then))) return o.then();
      while (t--) I(i[t], a(t), o.reject);
      return o.promise()
    }
  });
  var W = /^(Eval|Internal|Range|Reference|Syntax|Type|URI)Error$/;
  S.Deferred.exceptionHook = function(e, t) {
    C.console && C.console.warn && e && W.test(e.name) && C.console.warn("jQuery.Deferred exception: " + e.message, e.stack, t)
  }, S.readyException = function(e) {
    C.setTimeout(function() {
      throw e
    })
  };
  var F = S.Deferred();
```

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is a browser reading HTML, generating the content and exporting PDF. As far as I know, this is a project that is not maintained, so if your exported HTML is using modern JavaScript (let, const, `` strings, etc...) it might break. 
Today there are more modern ways to generate PDF using headless Chrome or it's open source version headless Chromium which will be generated with either Google Chrome / the open source Chromium.
you can read here about a library that using this flow: https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/
 or 
https://playwright.dev/

Comment: @GalGur-Arie I have more than 1000 HTMLs that I need to convert them into a single PDF, do you know if headless Chrome is able to do that?

Comment: @KJ i've added my command in the post. I'm supplying html as input, and in the html file the src points to jQuery.js.

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link href="tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dynsections.js"></script>
<link href="search/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="search/searchdata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="search/search.js"></script>
<link href="doxygen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

Comment: @KJ depending on the project size there might be that many HTMLs, but I guess I could break them into smaller chunks. Do you know then if headless Chrome is able to support that - multiple htmls into one PDF?

Comment: Why do you want to use an html to pdf converter and not the possibility in doxygen to create LaTeX output and run pdflatex on this (by means of a make procedure in the resulting latex directory)?